# Is every Abelian variety a direct summand of the Jacobian of a curve?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Though the answer is "yes" for Abelian varieties up to isogeny, the stronger statement is, perhaps, false. Does anyone know a counterexample?

Comment: No curve has a Jacobian that is a product as a ppav. I suppose a Jacobian might be a product not respecting polarization, but it seems unlikely to me.

Comment: Vadik, could you explain or give a reference for "yes" in the case of Abelian varieties up to isogeny?

Comment: The standard argument is to take a curve $C\subset A$ which is an
intersection of ample divisors, then $Jac(C)$ surjects onto $A$.
This map splits up to isogeny by Poincare reducibility.
Milne has some articles on abelian varieties and Jacobians, it's
probably in there.


Comment: @Ben It may happen that a jacobian is isomorphic to a product of abelian varieties (notv respecting polarization). See for instance 

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/35060/when-is-a-product-of-elliptic-curves-isogenous-to-the-jacobian-of-a-hyperelliptic,

in particular David Hansen comment and my answer.

Comment: Thanks, Francesco, but your answer does not seem compatible with David's. Maybe he left out an isogeny?